# Numpy build failure on Ubuntu Core (with snapcraft)

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, build, snapcraft

Finally I got my application snapped on Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 but now I try to snap it on Ubuntu Core (with my raspberry) and my python part (which depends on numpy) runs into following problem when building:

```
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy ... error
Complete output from command /home/getty23/cavi/cavi-device-snap/parts/cavi-device-sdk/install/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-9foo8C/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpewhEJRpip-wheel-:
Running from numpy source directory.
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
 libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/home/getty23/cavi/cavi-device-snap/parts/cavi-device-sdk/install/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
 NOT AVAILABLE
```

...
(more logs [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckjrxa8dfn4koly/NumpyProblem.txt?dl=0))
...

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c
 numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c:1838:5: error: ‘array_methods’     undeclared here (not in a function)
   array_methods,                              /* tp_methods */
   ^
numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c:1840:5: error: ‘array_getsetlist’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   array_getsetlist,                           /* tp_getset */
   ^
numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c:1838:5: error: ‘array_methods’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   array_methods,                              /* tp_methods */
   ^
numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c:1840:5: error: ‘array_getsetlist’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   array_getsetlist,                           /* tp_getset */
```

This is the part of the application which uses numpy:

```
parts:
 cavi-device-sdk:
  plugin: python
  python-version: python2
  source: ../cavi-device-sdk
  stage-packages:
  - liblapack-dev
  - libatlas-base-dev
  - gfortran
  - libatlas-dev
  - python-dev
  - libc6
  - python-numpy
```

I already tried to include different libraries (libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran libatlas-dev  python-dev) and I also moved back to an older numpy version 1.10.1. But nothing really helps.
It would be great if some numpy/snapcrafft expert could help me in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. Seems that I used the wrong numpy version. With numpy 1.11.0 and the following stage packages it was working:

```
 - gcc
 - gfortran
 - python-dev
 - libc6
 - libblas3
 - liblapack3
 - libopenblas-dev
 - liblapack-dev
 - cython
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides installing Miniconda, which installs an old version of numpy, I used the following steps:

`easy_install pip==1.5.6`
`pip install numpy==1.14.5`

Be sure you have `setuptools` and `wheel` latest versions. Sudo and chroot may also influence the process.

I documented my personal experience with Ubuntu Core at:

[GitHub Repo - Ubuntu Core in Raspberry](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/Raspberry%20Pi3%20IoT-Project)